# Add arrow symbol to plot label unicode - R

Tags: r, unicode

I'm trying to add a long arrow unicode U+27F5 to a label in a plot.

I can add the short arrow u2190, but the long arrow doesn't render.

Is this possible?

```
plot(mtcars$mpg, ylab =paste0("text ", "\u2190"))
plot(mtcars$mpg, ylab =paste0("text ", "\u27F5"))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Rendered _square_ instead `⟵` is `�` _Replacement Character_. This means that your font does not contain a glyph for `⟵`. Use e.g. _DejaVu Sans Mono_ font.

Comment: thank you @JosefZ, I'll give it a try!

Comment: @JosefZ: The square is not the U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER. It is a glyph; specifically, glyph 0 in the font. If a font doesn't support a character, it uses glyph 0 by default. U+FFFD is never used in rendering text; it gets used when transcoding into Unicode: "used to replace an incoming character whose value is unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode". https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFFF0.pdf But your guidance was right: use another font.

Comment: @PeterConstable thank you for information. Frankly, I never cared about TTF format in depth. I promise to read through [Character to Glyph Mapping (‘cmap’)](https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=IWS-Chapter08#ba57949e), ASAP:)